# Get clean ResponseStream when downloading multiple Ranges in c#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, chunks

I am downloading multiple ranges from a (binary) remote file:

I create a request and add multiple ranges

```
HttpWebRequest MyRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://.....");
MyRequest.AddRange(606665, 681711);
MyRequest.AddRange(813525, 913711);
```

then I run the request and process the response

```
HttpWebResponse MyResponse = (HttpWebResponse)MyRequest.GetResponse();
using (Stream MyResponseStream = MyResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
    // Open the destination file
    using (FileStream MyFileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\files\tempfile", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        // Create a 4K buffer to chunk the file
        byte[] MyBuffer = new byte[4096];
        int BytesRead;
        // Read the chunk of the web response into the buffer
        while (0 < (BytesRead = MyResponseStream.Read(MyBuffer, 0, MyBuffer.Length)))
        {
            // Write the chunk from the buffer to the file
            MyFileStream.Write(MyBuffer, 0, BytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, my problem is: The destination file contains header information at the beginning and between each chunk:

```
--4def9076831c13664
Content-type: text/plain
Content-range: bytes 606665-681711/57955496
```

How do I get the contents without these headers?

Comment: Actually, I did not find a solution for this. So I changed to code processing these files in a way that it will ignore the header, and instead search for the byte sequence each chunk starts with (I am lucky that I can do it this way).